# adding data from textbox to datatable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, datatable

I am trying to input data from a textbox to a datatable, but I cant seem to get it working properly. I have tried variables, objects, array and subroutines. none of the mentioned has worked out.

The program is simply a chart generator, it takes 5 variables from 5 textboxes and input them into a datatable in order to populate a line chart.

```
Dim dtTest As New DataTable
Dim a As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    dtTest.Columns.Add("Grades", GetType(Integer))
    dtTest.Columns.Add("Exams", GetType(Integer))

    dtTest.Rows.Add(1, a) // **it wont work with variables**
    dtTest.Rows.Add(2, 80) // 
    dtTest.Rows.Add(3, 60)
    dtTest.Rows.Add(4, 90)
    dtTest.Rows.Add(5, 70)

    With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)
        .AxisX.Minimum = 0
        .AxisX.Maximum = 6
        .AxisY.Minimum = 50
        .AxisY.Maximum = 100
        .AxisY.Interval = 10
        .AxisX.Title = "Grades"
        .AxisY.Title = "Exams"
    End With

End Sub
```

any help would highly be appreciated

Comment: Wha does not work? Where have you initialized the variable `a`? Where do you use the `DataTable`?

Comment: Please explain what kind of error are you observing. `Doesn't work` is the most useless explanation in our business

Comment: I wonder how can this code work if no variables are initialized (dtTest, a)... we need a little background to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Rafa: It actually works when you run it in Option Strict Off. Proper coding rules goes out the window. Heck one can even do dtTest.Rows.Add(1, "65") with successful results. But the post was probably edited after you typed your comment. So nvm. :P

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

After some testing my guess is that your problem is the lack of displayed data in the Chart. 
Add this (If you dont do the first line then "Derp" needs to be changed to "Series1" in the bottom two lines.):

```
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Name = "Derp"
    Chart1.Series("Derp").XValueMember = "Grades"
    Chart1.Series("Derp").YValueMembers = "Exams"
```

Comment: thing is I just want to input the data from textbox instead write them in Rows.Add(Att1,Att2)

Comment: So rows.add (1,convert.toint16 (textbox.text)) does not work? Cause your code Works fine to me.